# What are "equipment items"?

Tags: doom-2016

The game refers to "equipment items" in a rune and armor upgrade. Are they the weapon upgrades from the blue floating bots? Or items like grenades/chainsaw? Or something else?

Comment: Not sure why these were downvoted, but I also came upon the same question when unlocking the rune.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grenades/decoys/etc. are the "equipment". You can swap between them and they work under a timer system such that you can only use one every once in a while. There is a codex page with more information.

Comment: "They work under a timer system." Exactly what I was looking to know.